# how to iterate a Series with multiindex in pandas

Tags: pandas, series, multi-index

I am a beginner to pandas. And now I want to realise Decision Tree Algorithm with pandas. First, I read test data into a padas.DataFrame, it is like below:

```
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep = '\t')

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  Chocolate Vanilla Strawberry Peanut
0         Y       N          Y      Y
1         N       Y          Y      N
2         N       N          N      N
3         Y       Y          Y      Y
4         Y       Y          N      Y
5         N       N          N      N
6         Y       Y          Y      Y
7         N       Y          N      N
8         Y       N          Y      N
9         Y       N          Y      Y
```

then I groupby 'Peanut' and 'Chocolate', what I get is:

```
In [15]: df2 = df.groupby(['Peanut', 'Chocolate'])

In [16]: serie1 = df2.size()

In [17]: serie1
Out[17]:
Peanut  Chocolate
N       N            4
        Y            1
Y       Y            5
dtype: int64
```

Now, the type of serie1 is Series. I can access the value of serie1 but I can not get value of 'Peanut' and 'Chocolate. How can I get the number of serie1 and the value of 'Peanut' and 'Chocolate at the same time?

Comment: why can't you just reset the index? `serie1.reset_index()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `index`:

```
>>> serie1.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'N', u'Y'], [u'N', u'Y']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]],
           names=[u'Peanut', u'Chocolate'])
```

You can obtain the values of the column names and the levels. Note that the labels refer to the index in the same row in levels. So for example for 'Peanut' the first label is `levels[0][labels[0][0]]` which is 'N'. The last label of 'Chocolate' is `levels[1][labels[1][2]]` which is 'Y'.

I created a small example which loops through the indexes and prints all data:

```
#loop the rows
for i in range(len(serie1)):
   print "Row",i,"Value",serie1.iloc[i],
   #loop the columns
   for j in range(len(serie1.index.names)):
      print "Column",serie1.index.names[j],"Value",serie1.index.levels[j][serie1.index.labels[j][i]],
   print
```

Which results in:

```
Row 0 Value 4 Column Peanut Value N Column Chocolate Value N
Row 1 Value 1 Column Peanut Value N Column Chocolate Value Y
Row 2 Value 5 Column Peanut Value Y Column Chocolate Value Y
```

Comment: Thank you. So I can use serie1.index.levels and series.index.labels to get column's value. A bit confusing, I think it will take me several minutes to fully understand that. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, as you can see the values of `index.labels` are in fact indices of the arrays in `index.levels`. I hope you understand it with the example I put.